# Different space behaviour when compiling from source than when linking to a package

Tags: haskell

This code leaks or doesn't depending on how I compile the same RWS implementation:

```hs
import           Control.Monad         (replicateM_)
import qualified Control.Monad.RWS.CPS as RWS
import           Data.Monoid           (Sum (..))
-- import qualified RWS

{-# ann module "HLint: ignore Use camelCase" #-}

count_a_lot :: Int -> RWS.RWS () (Sum Int) () ()
count_a_lot = flip replicateM_ count

count :: RWS.RWS () (Sum Int) () ()
count = RWS.tell . Sum $ 1

main :: IO ()
main = print . snd $ RWS.evalRWS (count_a_lot 10000000) () ()
```

I experimented with two ways of using the CPS version of RWS:

- `import qualified Control.Monad.RWS.CPS as RWS` uses the `writer-cps-transformers` package, from nixpkgs.
- `import qualified RWS` uses [Internal.hs](https://github.com/minad/writer-cps-transformers/blob/6414485221b1487b9b1b16353e76243658a64d6a/src/Control/Monad/Trans/RWS/CPS/Internal.hs), copied verbatim as `RWS.hs` to the same local directory as the file pasted above.

If I compile the code above and run it, I can see that it runs in constant space.

[image: hs2ps, constant space]

If I change the imports to compile and link the copy of `RWS.hs`

```hs
import           Control.Monad (replicateM_)
-- import qualified Control.Monad.RWS.CPS as RWS
import           Data.Monoid   (Sum (..))
import qualified RWS
```

I get a space leak. The black retainer there is `(103)<*>.\`, and the blue is `SYSTEM`

[image]

Why can this be? Or how should I best debug this?

In both cases, I am compiling with ghc (no cabal) with `-Wall -O2 -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts -fexternal-interpreter`. I can post more detailed compiler invocation and output lines if it were relevant.

Using `ghc-8.4.4`, `transformers-0.5.5.0` and `writer-cps-transformers-0.1.1.4`. I know these versions are not current, but I am interested in knowing what is going on, rather on solving the actual leak, so I assume the versions aren't that relevant.

Comment: (1) I think there is a typo in the version of *transformers* you mention in the final paragraph, as 0.1.1.4 would be quite old. (2) On a tangential note, the latest version of transformers (0.5.6.2) provides that alternative `WriterT` as `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.CPS` (I know your question is not about that, but it doesn't hurt to use the occasion spread the word about it anyway).

Comment: There was a typo indeed, thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: I haven't dived into the code much here but expect it's the same reason all non-CC writer monads are a bad thing: https://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2016/7/writer-monads-and-space-leaks

Comment: Isn't `CPS.RWS` supposed to deal with that problem? It actually seems to run the counting in constant space in this case, but only if I compile against the library. In any case the question is why does the same code behave differently depending on how I compile and link in my example, I do understand why the basic Writer implementation leaks

Comment: Can you try without `-fprof-auto`? GHC does not correctly optimize when you have that on. This is because it doesn't optimize across cost centers. E.g. `sum $ map _a $ filter _b $ concatMap _c $ unfoldr _d` turns into a single loop with no lists in sight, but `sum $ map _a $ {-# SCC oof #-} filter _b $ concatMap _c $ unfoldr _d` can't become a loop, because where does the cost center go? With just `-fprof` and manual `SCC`s you can avoid the issue, but `-fprof-auto` is very stupid and has a tendency to break everything.

Comment: You are right! removing `-fprof-auto` does fix the problem when I link to my local copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is, in fact, the profiling system. Note that you don't actually need `-prof` to detect the space leak—the RTS option `-s` can print out a "total memory" measurement without it. Less scientifically, the space leak makes the program a lot slower, and you can just feel it. Armed with this, I found that disabling `-prof` reduced the memory usage of the "local" version to 2MB (the same as the "library" version), and leaving it on used ~1.9GB.

The reason profiling can make things slower is because GHC refuses to optimize as well. It can't aggressively restructure the code you write anymore, because the cost centers imply a certain structure to the code, and sometimes there's no good place for the cost center after an optimization, thereby blocking that optimization. Knowing precisely what's going wrong here would require knowing the flags with which you built the library, but the high-level explanation is that the `writer-cps-transformers` library was built with less aggressive profiling (and therefore more aggressive optimization) than the `RWS.hs` file. `-fprof-auto` is a very aggressive profiling option and it can easily break lots of optimizations. If I use a `writer-cps-transformers` built with `-fprof-auto`, I get the same issue. If I use a `RWS.hs` without profiling or with something weaker, like `-fprof-auto-exported`, then I fix the issue.